# Install of MINGW fails when installing from MSYS2

Tags: mingw, msys2, pacman-package-manager

I have MSYS2 installed on a Windows 11 machine, and in the terminal window for MSYS2 I use pacman to try to install MinGW but I get an immediate fail:

[image]

Anyone who has experienced the same thing, or could point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a fresh install? Did you install to the default installation directory?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This is a fresh install on a new machine. I haven't defined a particular directory so I assume it's using the default installation directory.

Comment: I see. Do you have only one `pacman` instance running? Maybe there's another one that didn't finish yet? Or maybe your antivirus is acting up?

Comment: To my knowledge I have only one instance of pacman running. As mentioned this is a new clean installation where I first installed MSYS2, and then searched for the correct mingw package with the command "pacman -Ss mingw-w64-i686-toolchain", and then chose to install the aforementioned package, i.e. "pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gcc"

Comment: Then I'd try disabling antivirus. (By two instances I meant having two terminal windows open from the same install, both running pacman).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Problem solved. Turned out that company policy, to my big surprise, prevented me to install since they regarded mingw as non-approved, hence the "Permission denied". This goes beyond my understanding since we are an ISV and software development is what we do. But starting last year they have hired some consultants to tighten up whatever they can securitywise, and this is obviously the result. But I now got it "white-listed" so all good :). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post shell output as properly-formatted text (monospaced) instead of images so it can easily searched and copied.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that company policy, to my big surprise, prevented me to install since they regarded mingw as non-approved, hence the "Permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

Since your company has a policy against installing MSYS2 you could consider using MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/ which requires no installer.
But if they block things like `gcc.exe` than that won't work either, but it's worth a try.